# Javascript Uncaught Reference Error: function is Not Defined

Tags: javascript

I am working with the Google Maps API to make a map that will display earthquakes, and I am trying to create a drop-down box to make it so users can set a minimum earthquake magnitude to display, and I've been having some issues.
Code to create drop down box:

```
controlText.innerHTML = "<select id='selMag' onchange='getSelMag(this)'>" +
                            "<option value='1.0'>Select Minimum Magnitude</option>" +
                            "<option value='1.0'>1.0</option>" +
                            "<option value='2.0'>2.0</option>" +
                            "<option value='3.0'>3.0</option>" +
                            "<option value='4.0'>4.0</option>" +
                            "<option value='5.0'>5.0</option>" +
                            "<option value='6.0'>6.0</option>" +
                            "<option value='7.0'>7.0</option>" +
                            "<option value='8.0'>8.0</option>" +
                            "<option value='9.0'>9.0</option>" +
                            "<option value='10.0'>10.0</option>" +
                        "</select>"
```

Code to get the value from the  tags:

```
var value;
var magnitude = (function getSelMag(sel) {
    var value = Number(sel.value);
    return value;
})();
console.log(magnitude);
```

When using this code I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/opmhT.png
(Note: line 15 is `var value = Number(sel.value);` line 18 is `})();` and the onchange line should be obvious. Also, I tried replacing `var value = Number(sel.value);` with `var value = 1;` to see if it would display in the logs with `console.log(magnitude);` and it did.)

Comment: Inline events are bad practice. Try adding the event in JavaScript. Look into `addEventListener`. To create elements look into `document.createElement`, instead of using strings.

Comment: well you do not pass in a select when you call it...

Comment: A named function expression is not the same thing as a regular function and can only be invoked by that name from within the function body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSelMag` is the name of the function assigned to `magnitude` that gets immediately invoked without any arguments. So you are left with:

```
var value = Number(undefined.value)
                   //^ Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
return value
```

Even if you pass an argument, I think you are misunderstanding the use of IIFEs and maybe functions in general. The name `getSelMag` is not available in scope, the variable `magnitude` is, thus `ReferenceError: getSelMag is not defined`. If you want to have a function named `getSelMag` in scope, you can use a function declaration:

```
function getSelMag(sel) {
  var value = Number(sel.value)
  return value
}
```

Or a function expression:

```
var getSelMag = function(sel) {
  ...
}
```

Note that functions have a `name` property:

```
var baz = function foo() {}
baz.name // foo
```

Above, `baz` is in scope, not `foo`.